# Specify insert order for fragments

Tags: merge, perforce, merge-conflict-resolution, p4merge

In P4Merge, if I select multiple colored icons in the right-hand pane while holding SHIFT (the blue icon corresponds to 'theirs' file, yellow - to 'base' and green - to 'mine'), all the corresponding fragments are inserted into the result:

[image]

But, the order of the insertion seems to be constant: first 'base', then 'theirs', and finally 'mine'. The order in which I select the icons doesn't affect the result.

**Can I somehow change this insertion order?** (Save for editing the result by hand, of course.) E.g. I'd like to insert 'theirs' fragment after 'mine'.

The tool version here is *P4Merge/NTX86/2012.1/475402* .

Comment: This is why Perforce frustrates the hell out of me, it doesn't handle the most basic of merge operations, like two revisions both adding to the same section.   The merge operation should just be to decide which revision goes before and after, but Perforce sees these as major conflicts that have to be edited by hand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not configurable.  Copying+pasting is the best workaround.